# How can I list all the dependencies necessary to install PHP-Soap?

Tags: centos, php, dependencies

I have a server running Centos 5.10 with no internet access that I control remotely on which I'd like to install PHP-Soap. I also have an identical box in the office which is a clone of the remote machine.

PHP-Soap is already installed on the local machine. I found that one can use `ldd` to list dependencies of an executable. But to run this you need an executable in the `/bin/` folder

So my question is: ***How can I list all dependencies needed to install PHP-Soap?***

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yum` to accomplish this.

```
[root@insomnia ~]# yum deplist php-soap
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.greenmountainaccess.net
 * epel: mirror.metrocast.net
 * extras: mirror.rackspace.com
 * updates: mirror.lug.udel.edu
package: php-soap.x86_64 5.4.16-21.el7
  dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
   provider: glibc.x86_64 2.17-55.el7
  dependency: libdl.so.2()(64bit)
   provider: glibc.x86_64 2.17-55.el7
  dependency: libm.so.6()(64bit)
   provider: glibc.x86_64 2.17-55.el7
  dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
   provider: glibc.x86_64 2.17-55.el7
  dependency: libxml2.so.2()(64bit)
   provider: libxml2.x86_64 2.9.1-5.el7
  dependency: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.4.30)(64bit)
   provider: libxml2.x86_64 2.9.1-5.el7
  dependency: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.5.7)(64bit)
   provider: libxml2.x86_64 2.9.1-5.el7
  dependency: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.0)(64bit)
   provider: libxml2.x86_64 2.9.1-5.el7
  dependency: libz.so.1()(64bit)
   provider: zlib.x86_64 1.2.7-13.el7
  dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-21.el7
   provider: php-common.x86_64 5.4.16-21.el7
  dependency: rtld(GNU_HASH)
   provider: glibc.x86_64 2.17-55.el7
   provider: glibc.i686 2.17-55.el7
```

Or you can use `repoquery` utility, if the older version of `yum` does not support the feature.

```
[root@insomnia ~]# repoquery --requires --resolve php-soap
php-common-0:5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64
glibc-0:2.17-55.el7.i686
zlib-0:1.2.7-13.el7.x86_64
libxml2-0:2.9.1-5.el7.x86_64
glibc-0:2.17-55.el7.x86_64
```